# How to read from files and input strings to vars?

Tags: c++

I have a list formatted like - String : Int, how would i seperate each one into individual strings?

I can't seem to figure out the separation part where it reads one space before the colon and one space after.

Comment: try [std::string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding right, you can read the file line by line, then separate the two elements you want with strtok() (if you're using null-terminated byte strings) or a combination of find() and substr() (if you're using std::strings)

I've worked with the former, so I'll explain what I'd do.

first, I'll read the whole line to a char array:

```
    #include <cstring>
    char temp[256];
    cin.getline(temp, 256);
```

then, with strtok I split the line into what you need

```
    char str[256], num[256]
    char *p = strtok(temp, ":");
    strcpy(str, p);
    p = strtok(NULL, ":");
    strcpy(num, p);
```

Make sure to change cin to whatever your file variable is named.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy. Edit: `strlcopy()` might be better / safer.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
string aStr;
char split;
int aInt;

while (ifs >> aStr >> split >> aInt) {
    // Dealing with these variables
}
```

Hope it helps