# Is it possible to point a char pointer to a whole string as I need the string to be printed?

Tags: c, pointers, char

C function to remove the first string from an XOR linked list of names:

```
int remove_string(Node **head, char *deleted_string) {
    Node *temp = *head;
    *deleted_string = *(*head)->name;
    *head = calculate_xor_value(NULL, temp->xor_value);
    if (*head != NULL) {
        (*head)->xor_value = calculate_xor_value(NULL, calculate_xor_value(temp, (*head)->xor_value));
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

In the question, one of the input parameters has to be a **char pointer** called ***deleted_string***, which is the string that is being removed from the list. The code to remove the string works fine *(line 4 onwards)*, but I am struggling to save the string to the `char* deleted_string` *(line 3)* `*deleted_string = *(*head)->name;`

Everytime I run the code
`// printf("%s", deleted_string );` only the first character is being printed; I think I understand that this is because pointers only point to the first character of a string, but is there a way to make the pointer point to the whole string? Perhaps by somehow converting `(*head)->name` to a string or an array?

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if this is a silly question. I have spent hours trying to find another page about this but I didn't so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: You don't use assignment to assign strings. You use `strcpy()`.

Comment: `strcpy(deleted_string, (*head)->name)`

Comment: Hint: What is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `(*head)->name` is of type `char*`, you are dereferencing both the `char *deleted_string` and `char *name`, hence operating on something of type `char`.

The line

```
*deleted_string = *(*head)->name;
```

is equivalent of doing something like

```
char a;
char b = 0;

a = b;
```

If you want to copy the contents of `(*head)->name` into the `deleted_string`, you can use `strcpy` or `strncpy` like,

```
strncpy( deleted_string, (*head)->name, SIZE );
```

Where the `SIZE` is whatever maximum size the `deleted_string` can hold. `strcpy` is the same, just without the size argument.

As comments suggested, both should be used with care, as `strcpy` can attempt to copy more characters than the destination can hold, causing write violations, and `strncpy` will truncate if the source is bigger than the destination, the resulting string will not necessarily be null-terminated. In such case, functions that assume the string is null-terminated will misbehave, such as `printf( "%s" ... )`, causing read violations. For more information, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy) post.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense, thanks for explaining it, I understand why this is the way to do it!