# string literal in c

Tags: c

Why is the following code illegal?

```
typedef struct{
   char a[6];
} point;

int main()
{
   point p;
   p.a = "onetwo";
}
```

Does it have anything to do with the size of the literal? or is it just illegal to assign a string literal to a char array after it's declared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning strings to arrays of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, because this is a struct containing a character array, which is subtly different from just a regular character array, I have explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't have anything to do with the size. You cannot assign a string literal to a char array after its been created - you can use it only at the time of definition.

When you do

```
char a[] = "something";
```

it creates an array of enough size (including the terminating null) and copies the string to the array. It is not a good practice to specify the array size when you initialize it with a string literal - you might not account for the null character.

When you do

```
char a[10];
a = "something";
```

you're trying to assign to the address of the array, which is illegal.

EDIT: as mentioned in other answers, you can do a strcpy/strncpy, but make sure that the array is initialized with the required length.

```
strcpy(p.a, "12345");//give space for the \0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can never assign to arrays after they've been created; this is equally illegal:

```
int foo[4];
int bar[4];
foo = bar;
```

You need to use pointers, or assign to an index of the array; this is legal:

```
p.a[0] = 'o';
```

If you want to leave it an array in the struct, you can use a function like `strcpy`:

```
strncpy(p.a, "onetwo", 6);
```

<sub>(note that the char array needs to be big enough to hold the nul-terminator too, so you probably want to make it `char a[7]` and change the last argument to `strncpy` to 7)</sub>

Comment: I guess I should be flattered that every answer edited in my `strcpy` solution

Comment: Here, have a +1. I'd +2 if I could, but I find it a bit odd that nobody has yet noticed that this is a `struct` containing an array, not just a plain array.

Comment: Of course, "strncpy" comes with its own problems, unlike most of the other "n" functions.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays are `non modifiable lvalues`. So you cannot assign to them. Left side of assignment operator must be an `modifiable lvalue`.

However you can initialize an array when it is defined.

For example :

```
 char a[] = "Hello World" ;// this is legal
 char a[]={'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','\0'};//this is also legal

 //but

 char a[20];
 a = "Hello World" ;// is illegal
```

However you can use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/)`(a, "Hello World",20);`

Comment: It would be clearer if you used the correct term 'initialize' instead of 'assign' when an array is 'defined' (rather than 'declared').

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have already pointed out, you can only initialise a character array with a string literal, you cannot assign a string literal to a character array. However, structs (even those that contain character arrays) are another kettle of fish.

I would not recommend doing this in an actual program, but this demonstrates that although arrays types cannot be assigned to, structs containing array types can be.

```
typedef struct
{
    char value[100];
} string;

int main()
{
    string a = {"hello"};
    a = (string){"another string!"}; // overwrite value with a new string
    puts(a.value);

    string b = {"a NEW string"};
    b = a; // override with the value of another "string" struct
    puts(b.value); // prints "another string!" again
}
```

So, in your original example, the following code should compile fine:

```
typedef struct{
    char a[6];
} point;

int main()
{
   point p;

   // note that only 5 characters + 1 for '\0' will fit in a char[6] array.
   p = (point){"onetw"};
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `struct` examples, but note that these compound literals are a C99 addition. (Same goes for the '//' style comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to store the string "onetwo" in your array, it has to be of length [7] and not as written in the question. The extra character is for storing the '\0' terminator.

Answer (score 1):

No strcpy or C99 compund literal is needed. The example in pure ANSI C:

```
typedef struct{
   char a[6];
} point;

int main()
{
   point p;
   *(point*)p.a = *(point*)"onetwo";
   fwrite(p.a,6,1,stdout);fflush(stdout);
   return 0;
}
```