# C string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [string literal in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473765/string-literal-in-c)
>   [Assigning strings to arrays of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters)

I got the following code:

```
char result[3][4];

result[0] = "horse";
result[1] = "pig";
result[2] = "chicken";
```

It won't compile saying `Incompatible types in assignment`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well those are char* and not char[4]...

Comment: @birryree: That question has its own possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

char is a single char, eg 'h'

What you want is string pointers.

```
 char *result[3];
```

Remember if you do it this way you won't be able to change the contents of an individual string (it is a constant and stored in a different place.)

You could also do something like this

```
 char *result[3];

 result[0] =  malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
 strcpy(result[0],"horse"); // or strncpy(result[0],5,"horse")
 etc
```

Comment: In OP's example `result` is a `char [3][4]`, and `result[i]` is thus a `char[4]`, not a `char`.

Comment: @peoro : true.  Perhaps I could phrase the answer better.

Comment: @user282635 : read this answer too, it might make things clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters

Answer (score 2):

```
char result[3][10] = {
  "horse", 
  "pig", 
  "chicken",
}
```

or

```
char result[3][10];

strcpy_s(result[0], 10, "horse");
strcpy_s(result[1], 10, "pig");
strcpy_s(result[2], 10, "chicken");
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works better:
char result[3][10] = {"horse", "pig", "chicken"};

Also, have in mind that "chicken" and "horse" have more that 4 characters and therefore result[3][4] (the [4] part) is not that right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted:

```
char* result[3];
result[0] = "horse";
result[1] = "pig";
result[2] = "chicken";
```

What you did was wrong for two reasons.

First, you can't "assign" a string to a char array like that, you'd have to use, for example, `strcpy`.

Second, your array dimension was also wrong, `char array[4]` obviously won't hold `"horse"` or `"chicken"`, so it wouldn't work even if you corrected what I said above (it would compile, but you would be writing to memory you shouldn't be writing to).

What the corrected code does, is instead of storing the char array per se, it stores a pointer to the location in memory where `"horse"`, etc., are stored. Therefore, it just stores an address, and you can then use the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are non-modifiable `lvalues` i.e you cannot assign to them.

You need to use array of pointers. Change `char result[3][4];` to `char * result[3]`

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because `result` declared as `char result[3][4]` and used as `result[0]` will result in something **similar** with: `char * const result`. Constant pointer doesn't admit any assignment, it already contains pointer to the array of columns "`[4]`".

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a string literal (eg: `"horse"`) to a `char` array only when you declare it, not after.

```
char array[4] = "str"; // is OK
char array2[4];
array2 = "str"; // is NOT OK.
```

You could do like this:

```
char result[3][4] = { "horse", "pig", "chicken" };
```

but warning: `"horse"` and `"chicken"` are longer than `char[4]`.

---

If you want to assign a string literal to an already declared `char` array you'll have to use `strcpy` (or other similar functions).

---

The other solution, suggested by many is to declare `result` as an array of char pointers: `char *result[3];`, but if you do like this you won't be allowed to modify the content of the strings pointed by `result[i]`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to increase the size of the words and use `strcpy()`:

```
char result[3][8];    // at least 8!

strcpy(result[0], "horse");
strcpy(result[1], "pig");
strcpy(result[2], "chicken");
```

Comment: @downvoter: have you tried compile my code and run it?? It works perfectly!

Comment: Your initial code was nonsense and you know it. If you'd said "I've fixed it so it's no longer nonsense", I'd have removed the downvote. Instead you choose to play dumb, so the downvote stands.

Comment: @Nicholas: I didn't know you downvoted __before__ I fixed it.