# Delivery Program using Structure C

Tags: c++, string, system, structure

I'm making a delivery system like the McDelivery system using structures.
I have this code to store the customer's order data and his/her info.

```
struct customer
{
    int contactno;
    char firstname[20], lastname[20];

    struct order
    {
        struct date
        {
            int day, month, year;
        }orderdate;

    }o;
}c;
```

Then I used array to store the item's info and i have this code

```
int spaghetti[2], fries[2], icecream[2], MonsterMcBurger[2], SuicideBurger[2], VeggieWhooper[2], GrandSlam[2],  BiscottiFrappuccino[2], CaptainCrunch[2], PizzaSub[2];
```

I have no problem inserting the price of each item but I'm having trouble on how you put the item's name in array. Is it possible to assign a text in array? if not what code should I use to store the name and the price of the item at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    customer cust;
    strcpy(cust.firstname, "John");
    strcpy(cust.lastname, "Smith");
}
```

this is a very `C` way of doing things though; `C++` can handle this in a better way, for instance, by using `std::string`. so instead of `char firstname[20], lastname[20];`, you'd have `std::string firstname, lastname;`, and your assignment would look like this:

```
int main() {
    customer cust;
    cust.firstname = "John";
    cust.lastname = "Smith";
}
```

also, to answer your question, it's not possible to assign values to an array of chars in the way you want to, [see here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10088684/1974937).