# Assigning a string to a char array in a structure in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, string, struct, char

I should mention that I am on Turbo C++ (yes the old one) because it is required by my school.

I have a structure like this:

```
struct move{
 int power;
 int pp;
 char name[10];
 };
```

When I try to make a new variable if I do this:

```
move tackle;
tackle.pp = 10;
tackle.power = 20;
tackle.name = "tackle";
```

I get an error as:

`Error NONAME00.CPP 11: Lvalue required`

But this works:

`move tackle = {20, 10, "tackle"}`

it works.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. line 11 is the `tackle.name = "tackle"`, sorry if I was unclear earlier.

Comment: The mysterious line 11, where is it? Can you add a line count?

Comment: I think just indicating which line produces the error will suffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning a string of characters to a char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088661/assigning-a-string-of-characters-to-a-char-array)

Comment: `because it is required by my school`  A school who's intent is to turn out programmers who do not know C++ as it stands today (or even 17 years ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to an array, but you can initialise it.

```
tackle.name = "tackle";
```

is an assignment, while

```
move tackle = {20, 10, "tackle"};
```

is an initialisation.

To replace the contents of the array, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(tackle.name, "tackle");
```

or, better, use `string` if you're allowed to:

```
#include <string>

struct move{
 int power;
 int pp;
 string name;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a c-style string and you should initialize it via

```
strcpy(tackle.name, "tackle");
```

Comment: even better: `strncpy(tackle.name, "tackle", 9)`

Comment: @WorldSEnder `strncpy(dest, src, 9)` is not better - does not guarantee `dest` has a terminating `'\0'`.  `tackle.name[0] = 0;  strncat(dest, src, sizeof dest)` does.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
tackle.name = "tackle";
```

tries to assign one array to another which not a supported operation in C or C++.

However initialization like `char name[10] = "tackle"` is fine by the standard and is supported.