# Does not name a type error (on a variable) c++

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct user {
    char username[20];
    char password[20];
} admin;
admin.username = "admin"; admin.password = "password";
```

So I'm getting a compiler error saying that admin does not declare a type.
It gives this error when trying to declare both admin.username and admin.password

To be honest I am completely perplexed here and can't see whats wrong.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Don't bother with C strings unless you have to.

Comment: You allocated the memory for the strings already. You should copy the strings instead of assigning. See strcpy function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: If you want to use C-style strings, you'll need to use C-style `strcpy` or similar.

Comment: Can you copy and paste here the compiler error you are getting? The struct should compile just fine. The assignment is the only problem.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious no it is not here, it is a variable of type `struct user`

Comment: you cannot assign values to structure  member variables in global scope but you can do this with global normal variables

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters

Answer (score 0):

`admin` is a variable of type `struct user` but you need to put assignments in a function to run the code.  also you need to declare username and password as pointers, so you can easily assign literals to them . you cannot do that in global scope.

```
struct user {

    const char *  username;
    const char * password;
} admin;


int main()
{
    admin.username = "admin";
    admin.password = "password";

}
```

alternative way is to do it like this:

```
    struct  {

    const   char  * username;
    const   char  * password;

    }  admin = { "user", "password" };
```

or like this if still need to identify the structure:

```
struct  user {

    const char  * username;
    const char  * password;

}  admin = { "user", "password" };
```