# What is the underlying mechanism of char array[] = "string"?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I know that in C string assignment must go through

```
char string[4];
strcpy(string, "aaa");
```

but why and how does C allow

```
char string[] = "string";
```

?

Thanks in advance

Comment: C has never had( and never will?) a native a string type. A character sequence terminated by `\0` is a considered a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: @P.P. Not exactly the same - this is the difference between `char string[4]` and `char string[]` while the other is between `char string[]` and `char *string`.

Comment: Probably this link could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood something. According to gcc you **are** allowed to do:

```
char string[4] = "aaa";
```

The difference to `char string[] = "aaa";` is only that the compiler infers the length of `string` from it's initializer. There's nothing different to other types of arrays here - just the fact that you may use a string literal as an initializer instead of an array literal.

Comment: I assigned a string to a character array char string[] = "aaa" but I could change the content afterwards. No errors.

Comment: @FabioTurati I removed that paragraph so your comment about my last paragraph only applies to a paragraph that is no longer present...

Answer (score 2):

```
char string[] = "string";
```

Here, the *right* length of `string` is automatically calculated by the compiler so that there's enough room for the string and the NUL character.

```
char string[4];
strcpy(string, "aaa");
```

Here `strcpy` may access beyond the array bounds if the string is larger than the actual `string` capacity.

Comment: If strcpy can access beyond the array bounds does that mean it assigns memory address for the array depending on the size of the string?

Comment: No, it just keeps on writing in the following memory addresses, occupied by other variables, producing undefined results. This technique is used for buffer overflow attacks, so if you are doing strcpy from strings given by user, you must check first that the size of the destination buffer is big enough.

Comment: @hemel: No, it does not resize the array (what you say): that's _your_ job. It's just writes past the bounds of the array, leading to UB.

Comment: So if there was a preoccupied memory address following the one occupied by the array and the string is quite long, could it corrupt the data in the preoccupied memory address?