# Printing a structure string issue

Tags: c, printf

I am having some troubles with printing out a structure

```
struct player
{
    char name[20];
}
```

The issue that I am having is that when I call out this struct in the main function.

```
int main()
{
    struct player First;
    First.name = "Example";
    printf("Name is: %s", First.name);
}
```

There is an error with "First.name = "Example"", I do not know what is wrong with it. The error says "error: assignment to expression with array type" I looked at videos and its seem that they are doing the same thing what I did.

I tried to find a question in this website with a similar problem, but I can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters#579758

Comment: how about if i want to use fgets? example: fgets(First.name, 20, stdin);