# Why does changing the character of a string not give the desired character?

Tags: c

I am trying to edit a string after initialization using character literals, as follows:

```
int main() {
    char str1[10] = "hello";
    str1[0] = "b";
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is "dello" i.e. a "d" not a "b". Likewise the below just gives nonsense.

```
int main() {

    char str1[10];

    str1[0] = "h";
    str1[1] = "e";
    str1[2] = "l";
    str1[3] = "l";
    str1[4] = "o";

    printf("%s\n", str1);
}
```

I found one StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters) that mentioned that this should cause a segfault or an Access-Violation error, but it doesn't really explain why.

Comment: `str1[0] = "b";` ==> `str1[0] = 'b';`

Comment: "... using character literals..." - those aren't character literals; they're *string* literals.

Comment: You MUST heed compiler warnings. Your code generates several in GCC without even turning on extra warnings.

Comment: Did you not get something like: *"warning C4047: '=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'"*? Please enable compiler warnings and consider them to be errors.

Comment: In C, `'b'` means "the number 66" (assuming ASCII), which is what you wanted, as opposed to `"b"` which means "the address in memory of two bytes I want you to allocate and fill with the numbers 66 and 0".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
str1[0] = "b";
```

Here, `"b"` is a string literal, *not* a character. Characters are enclosed in single quotes:

```
str1[0] = 'b';
```

If you had compiler warnings enabled you'd get something like:

> warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
>
> ```
> str1[0] = "b";
>         ^ ~~~
> ```

---

In your second code, your string is missing a terminating [null-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), and so passing it to `printf` invokes undefined behavior because `printf` can't know where your string ends. To append the null-character at the end, just do:

```
str1[5] = '\0';
```

Comment: you should also either initiallize str1 like this: `char str1[10] = {0};` or set `str1[5] = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks very much! (My compiler said "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]", which meant nothing to me)

Answer (score 3):

In C, single quotes identify chars and double quotes create a string literal.

Try doing the following:

```
str1[0] = 'b'; //note the single quote
```