# How can I resolve segmentation fault in my code.?

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, stack

I am trying to solve the problem of brackets matching i.e. given a sequence of opening and closing parenthesis `exp`, consisting of  `(` or `)`, square brackets  `[` or `]` or curly braces `}` or `{`, I need to tell if the given sequence is balanced or not.

```
Sample Input1:
exp = "[]{}()"

Sample Output1:
Match Successfull....!


----------


Sample Input2:
exp = "[]{(]}()"

Sample Output1:
Match not Successfull....!
```

PS: empty string is considered a balanced string.
Below is the code written in C where I tried to implement a stack using `struct`. I implemented the all the necessary function of a stack i.e., `pop()`, `push()`, `isFull()` etc.
However, I am getting segmentation fault. Please help me rectify the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int push(struct stack *ptr, char val) {
    if (isFull(ptr))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *ptr) {
    char val;
    if (isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top--;
        val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        return val;
    }
}

int match(char a, char b) {
    if (a == '{' && b == '}' || a == '(' && b == ')' || a == '[' && b == ']')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int parMatch(char *exp) {
    struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->arr = (char *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(char));
    s->size = 100;
    s->top = -1;
    char char_pop;
    for (int i = 0; exp[i] = '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
        {
            push(s, exp[i]);
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        char_pop = pop(s);
        if (!match(char_pop, exp[i]))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *exp = "[]{}()";
    if (parMatch(exp))
    {
        printf("Match Successfull....!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Match not Successfull....!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code results in an error is due to the statement `exp[i] = '\0';` in your condition of `for` loop. This is logically incorrect (explained below) and you just cannot modify strings declared using `char*`.

Why is that you ask? Read [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a “char *s” initialized with a string literal, but not “char s[]”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

---

You had other several errors as well within your code:

1. This is not how you assign strings in c, `char *exp = "[]{}()";`. Although it does work but it generates a warning and is not recommended. Read [Assigning strings to arrays of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters).
2. You have not initialized `s->size` but you are using it in `malloc()` in this line `s->arr = (char *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(char));`.
3. You declared the return-type of `push()` function as `int` but did not return anything after the `else` condition. This is a potential bug in future. It also results in warnings.
4. The implementation of your `pop()` function has logical as well as syntactical flaws. The return-type of `pop()` function is `int` but you return `char` type. Also, you first decrement `ptr->top` and then return the character at the new `ptr->top` location i.e, you end up returning the character which is below your current top.
5. This is not `exp[i] = '\0'` how you check the terminating condition of for loop for ending `char*` string in c. You should instead write `exp[i] != '\0'`.
6. You `return 0;` as soon as you encounter `)` or `}` or `]`. You should instead check whether you can pop a corresponding opening brace from the stack, if yes then check for further characters `else return 0;`

Below is the code with all the above-mentioned errors fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int push(struct stack *ptr, char val) {
    if (isFull(ptr))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
    return 0;
}

char pop(struct stack *ptr) {
    char val;
    if (isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        return '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return val;
    }
}

int match(char a, char b) {
    if ((a == '{' && b == '}') || (a == '(' && b == ')') || (a == '[' && b == ']'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int parMatch(char exp[]) {
    struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->size = 100;
    s->arr = (char *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(char));

    s->top = -1;
    char char_pop;
    for (int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
        {
            push(s, exp[i]);
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {   // You have one closing brace but your stack is empty, then return 0
            if (isEmpty(s))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {   // If you reach here then it ensures that stack is not empty.
                char_pop = pop(s);
                if (!match(char_pop, exp[i]))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char exp[100] = "{}}[](";
    if (parMatch(exp))
    {
        printf("Match Successfull....!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Match not Successfull....!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```